# Android: Sine Wave Generation

Tags: java, android, waveform

I'm trying to use AudioTrack to generate sine, square, and sawtooth waves. However, the audio this is creating doesn't sound like a pure sine wave, but like it has some kind of other wave overlayed. How would I go about getting the pure sine wave like in the second code example, while using the method in my first example? Since the top example only moves around some of the arithmetic used in the second, shouldn't they produce an identical wave?

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... foo) {
            short[] buffer = new short[1024];
            this.track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            float samples[] = new float[1024];

            this.track.play();

            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
                    samples[i] = (float) Math.sin( (float)i * ((float)(2*Math.PI) * frequency / 44100));    //the part that makes this a sine wave....
                    buffer[i] = (short) (samples[i] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
                }
                this.track.write( buffer, 0, samples.length );  //write to the audio buffer.... and start all over again!

            }           
        }
```

Note: This does give me a pure sine wave:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... foo) {
            short[] buffer = new short[1024];
            this.track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            float increment = (float)(2*Math.PI) * frequency / 44100; // angular increment for each sample
            float angle = 0;
            float samples[] = new float[1024];

            this.track.play();

            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
                    samples[i] = (float) Math.sin(angle);   //the part that makes this a sine wave....
                    buffer[i] = (short) (samples[i] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
                    angle += increment;
                }
                this.track.write( buffer, 0, samples.length );  //write to the audio buffer.... and start all over again!

            }           
        }
```

Thanks to Martijn: The problem is that the wave is getting cut off between wavelengths in the buffer. Increasing the buffer size solves the problem in the second example. It appears that the Math.PI * 2 arithmetic was the most intensive of the loop, so moving that value to an external variable that is only computed once solves everything.

Comment: It sounds like you might be hearing some aliasing or clipping.  Try reducing the amplitude of the sound wave you are generating.

Comment: So why not use the code that works?  I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Robert, I want to also create square and sawtooth waves, but the whole angle and increment idea confuses me when dealing with higher level wave functions.

Comment: You seem to understand it well enough to get the code to work.  "Any suggestions" is not a real question.  Try to make your question more specific.

Comment: Edited the question to be more specific. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Try to optimise your code by 1) increase buffer size, 2) prepare the buffer once, and keep rewriting it to the output stream (this will require some math calculating the perfect size for the buffer to make sure that the whole sine wave fits perfectly in it).

Comment: thanks Martijn, that is on my to-do list once I get the wave itself coming out with less noise.

Comment: I think what @martijn means is that you need to make sure that part of the wave form is not getting cut off horizontally.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. As in the buffer may be ending the wave between a full wavelength, causing the wave to deform at the beginning and end of every buffer push?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: To clarify, because "horizontally" is a bit confusing: it shouldn't be cut of in time. So can say that the buffer size should be relatively 3.14159265, because the period of a sine is Pi.

Comment: @user1000229: Exactly. I'm saying this because I suspect the buffer to taking to long to prepare, what causes a lag between two buffer pushes to big, which might be causing the noise.

Comment: That was it! I increased the buffer to 4096 bytes and the period between the noises definitely decreased. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to optimise your code by

1. increase buffer size
2. prepare the buffer once, and keep rewriting it to the output stream (this will require some math calculating the perfect size for the buffer to make sure that the whole sine wave fits perfectly in it).

Why? Because I suspect the buffer to taking to long to prepare, what causes a lag between two buffer pushes to big, which might be causing the noise.

Answer (score 2):

The only material difference that I can see in your two code samples is that the equation in your first example contains an integer (`I`), and therefore you're probably doing integer (not floating-point) arithmetic.  This would cause a staircasing effect, adding unwanted harmonics to your waveform.

I suspect that if you simply cast `I` to a float in your equation, it will produce a pure sine wave.

```
samples[i] 
    = (float) Math.sin( (float)i * ((float)(2*Math.PI) * frequency / 44100));
```

Comment: Casting the i to a float will not effect the calculation at all.

Comment: @you786 Yeah, alright.  I think we've already established that.

Answer (score 1):

None of these anwers fixes the problem. The buffer length should be a multiple of the sample rate, or at least the length of one rotation. Let's break it in ton of variables to show what's happening:

```
int sampleRate = 44100;
int bitsPerChannel = 16;
int bytesPerChannel = bitsPerChannel / 8;
int channelCount = 1;
int bytesPerSample = channelCount * bytesPerChannel;
int bytesPerRotation = sampleRate * bytesPerSample * (1d / (double) frequency);
```

Then you can multiply this `bytesPerRotation` by anything, it won't change a fact: there won't be glitch in the sound.