# Cannot find method in Android Session?

Tags: android

```
 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                      return new PasswordAuthentication("user-name", "user-password");
                    }
                  });
```

Here, I get several errors. As below:

```
Rename in file, Link all references for a local rename (does not change reference in other files)
```

What should I do?

Comment: javax.mail. is not part of the android sdk

Comment: so, I need to import it?

Comment: import javax.mail.Authenticator;
Yet same issue at getDefaultInstance

is asking for renaming it.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app/16811778#16811778

Comment: It is issue on getDefaultInstance. Can't even recognise it, asking for rename. Now what should I do?

Comment: Which `Session` are you talking about? Can you give the fully qualified name?