# Test Java code on an android tablet?

Tags: android, testing, emulation, tablet

I'm finding it impossible to test code on an android tablet. I'm looking to test my Java code so that I can play around with it. It's a very simple beginner's code - like just showing some text in separate lines. I have Droid edit and it doesn't let me view the converted product. I have an android app which is made for Java but I can't test my own code, only the code they provide in their tutorials.

Is it even possible to test my code and see how it would appear on a browser on a tablet? Is there not any App or task I could perform on my tablet to do this? It's  Linux Kernels after all, right?...

Comment: You need to learn the basics of the Android platform/architecture. Here is an answer that I wrote that may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app/16811778#16811778

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact technical details but Android requires code to be compiled against the Android framework and packed as an .apk, there's no official way of just slamming a jar file on your tablet and run it. 
Googling 'run jar on Android' brought [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2325619)