# How to use javax.xml.transform.stax in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javax.xml

I'm running into a strange problem in Android Studio. I'm also using latest JDK. I can't seem to import the following :

- javax.xml.stream
- javax.xml.transform.stax

They both are unavailable and I don't know why. In a non android project I'm able to import these. Any clue why these are missing in android?

If not, the simple solution is that I added these dependencies from maven. But after running I'm getting this error:

**"Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library.**

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't use the same Java JDK as what you use for a desktop or server app; it uses its own implementation of the JDK, which adds the `android.*` hierarchy but leaves out some packages that are in the standard JDK, especially in the `javax.*` Java extensions. Unfortunately for you, `javax.xml.stream` and `javax.xml.transform.stax` are among the things they didn't choose to implement. Moreover, the Android runtime won't allow you to load any `java.*` or `javax.*` classes from an external JAR file for security reasons**. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16811778/314890) may describe the situation a little better.

Your best bets are probably: 1) use a different third-party library specifically built for Android, such as [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/); 2) look for a repackaged version of the libraries, like [this JAXB effort](https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/); or 3) use a tool like [Jar Jar Links](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar) to do the repackaging for you.

Also see this excellent [guide](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/SiriRestClient/wiki/Parsing-JSON-and-XML-on-Android) on parsing JSON and XML in Android.

** Note: I can't find any documentation from Google to substantiate this; it's just a commonly repeated "fact". If anyone can point to an authoritative statement about Android's handling of third-party `java[x].*` classes, please comment with a link, or edit this answer.