# Why can't I import javax.sound.sampled. when they seem to show in my libraries?

Tags: android-studio, javax.sound.sampled

I am trying to use some of the classes from the javax.sound.sampled libraries.  But even though, to my novice eyes, the files are there, AndroidStudio won't import them.

Is something not set properly?

[Image of libraries as shown in AndroidStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFC7w.gif)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.\* cannot be imported in my Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app)

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't think this should be considered a duplicate.  Different environments, and again to my naïve eyes, the library seems to be available if you look at the image I included.

Comment: That is the standard Java library (for some reason) not an Android library.

Comment: It is absolutely a duplicate.  Your screen shot shows you are browsing around in a JDK, the libraries of which are of no applicability.  These class do not exist in the Android SDK - you will have to rewrite whatever you want to accomplish in terms of those that do.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the module-info.java from the default package.