# Javax in android

Tags: android, javax

I was using SourceDataLine and AudioFormat in

> javax Netbeans

And I want to use them in an android project. Is there is any similar methods in android?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app